# Modifying Views in a Layout assoicated with a Fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I'm new to Android development. I've written a simple app to understand the flow of things, using activities and fragments. Now I'm trying to write an app that will hopefully be of use to people.

I'm running into problems with fragments. The problem occurs with the layout that has been inflated by the system after a call to onCreatView().

Here's the situation: I'm trying to get things working using a tablet screen emulator. I've gotten the code to display the list on the left side of the screen and the new layout appears on the right side once an item in the list is selected. The problem is I can't do anything with the layout in the fragment on the right side, and this may be just the way fragments work. They appear to be read only. If that's the case then I will have to approach the design of the overall app differently.

You see, there are views associated with the layout in the fragment that I want to be able to access and modify the content of (TextView, EditText...). The methods I need (but are not available in a fragment) are findViewById() and setText(Charsequence text) and the other set... methods. These are available at the activity level, but the inflated layout is not there.

So, is there another way to gain access to these views within a fragment to modify them? Or is something being done to add these types of methods to the fragment class to allow one to access and modify the content of views associated with a particular fragment. For now it looks like I'm going to have to use different activities to accomplish what I thought could happen by using fragments.

Perhaps someone has dealt with this type of problem and can offer some insight. Your help is appreciated because I've been trying to resolve this for days now, and I haven't found an answer in my searching.

Thanks in advance,

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the methods you mentioned in the fragments.

This is example how to inflate layout and get the view object from that layout.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // inflate layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_frag, null);

    // get the WebView object that is in the layout
    WebView wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wv);
}
```

Comment: Martin, thanks for the help. It's works. Now on to the next challenge. Again thanks much.